# Can I control HSA config generated by AMDGPU backend?

Tags: clang, gpu, llvm, opencl, amd-gpu

I am using LLVM Clang to offline compile my OpenCL code into assembly. My target is amdgpu--amdhsa. The assembly file generated by clang has config of `enable_sgpr_dispatch_ptr = 1`. Can I do something to turn that off in the generated assembly file? Also, it seems that the order of kernel arguments is in the reverse order of AMDCL2 convention. i.e. user argument is placed at the first place while hidden arguments like `HiddenGlobalOffsetX` are placed after user arguments. Can I change the order of the arguments so that the first argument will be hidden arguments before user arguments?

Comment: Turns out I need to modify llvm code to change the offset and order for those implicit kernel args. But I still don't know how to disable enable_sgpr_dispatch_ptr  intrinsic.